# Wp redirect - reset password

Tags: php

I'm stuck. I am doing a redirection from the approve post function to the link that establishes the password. This works, but it does not take the user.
that is, open the page of reset password but I see the error that the user was not designated.

am I calling the variable wrong?
Thanks in advance.

```
 add_action('init', 'approve_post', 10, 2 );

 add_action('edit_user_created_user', 'approve_post', 10, 2 );

 function approve_post($user, $notify) {

 if ( isset($_GET['approve']) && isset($_GET['email']) ) {
// have we all variable needed?
if ( empty($_GET['approve']) || ! filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) return;
// get post
$post = get_post($_GET['approve']);
// this post has an author?
if ( ! isset($post->post_author) ) return;
// is the post already published?
if ( $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
  wp_redirect("" . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . "");
  exit();
} elseif ( $post->post_status != 'pending' ) { // was the post deleted by admin?
  return;
}
// get the author
$author = new WP_User($post->post_author);
// check author variable
if ( ! isset($author->user_email) ) return;
// verify email
if ( $_GET['email'] != $author->user_email ) return;
// verify key
$key = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_approve_key', true);
if ( $key != md5( $author->user_email . $post->ID ) ) return;
// ok, update status
$post_data = array('ID' => $post->ID, 'post_status' => 'publish');
$update = wp_update_post($post_data);
// update failed...
if ( ! $update ) return;
// delete verify key
delete_post_meta($post->ID, '_approve_key');
// work finished, view the post
wp_redirect("" . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . "");
exit();
 } return $notify;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Revised answer)*

The problem with your code is that the password reset link/URL is missing the proper password *reset key* and user login slug — the `$key` (password reset key) and `$user_login` (user login slug) as you can see below, are both missing (i.e. not defined anywhere in your code):

```
network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login')
```

So to fix the problem:

1. Replace this:

   ```
   if ( $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
     wp_redirect("" . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . "");
     exit();
   }
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   if ( $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
     if ( ! $user = get_user_by( 'email', $_GET['email'] ) ) return;
     $key = get_password_reset_key( $user );
     wp_redirect("" . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user->user_login), 'login') . "");
     exit();
   }
   ```
2. Replace this:

   ```
   // work finished, view the post
   wp_redirect("" . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . "");
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   // work finished, view the post
   $key = get_password_reset_key( $author );
   wp_redirect("" . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($author->user_login), 'login') . "");
   ```

And note that the `init` hook doesn't pass any parameters to the callback function (which in your case is `approve_post()`), so your code should be just:

```
add_action( 'init', 'approve_post' );
```

So the `approve_post()` function should be defined *without any parameters*:

```
function approve_post() // like this
function approve_post($user, $notify) // not this
```

And hooking to the `init` action only is enough; so this is not necessary:

```
add_action('edit_user_created_user', 'approve_post', 10, 2 );
```

This is also not necessary — **at the end** of the function (before the closing `}`), you don't need to return anything:

```
return $notify; // just remove this
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your time. I try this `add_action('init', 'approve_post', 10, 2 );
add_action('edit_user_created_user', 'approve_post', 10, 2 );

function approve_post( $user, $notify) {  ..... return $notify;
}
` but itsnt work. Is possible two action for one function? @sally-cj

Comment: Hi Jennifer. "*the link that establishes the password*" - how does the link look like? Is it a standard password reset link generated by WordPress? If not, can you add to your question the code which generates the link?

Comment: Hi Sally. Yes it is Standard of WordPress. . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') .

Comment: I may have misunderstood the "reset password" thing. How does the whole process works? What are the steps - e.g. click a link (what link and how it looks like), etc. ? I know the `approve_post()` function is changing the post status (to `publish`), but how does it get triggered? Perhaps you can add the steps to your question?

Comment: Exactly. My page sent a email to the user. It have a unique link to approve the post and create the password. I need it unique

Comment: Ok, so the link looks like `http://example.com/?approve=123&email=user@email.com` ? If yes, let me test your code and I'll be back soon.

Comment: Right. That link is generated to approve the post. automatically directs to the other link that generates the password (url sent) with the filter $wp_new_user_notification_email thanks a lot!

Comment: I've updated the answer. Try the steps and let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: You are a genious! Thank you very much for your time and dedication worked perfect!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it worked. :)